# The webpage cannot be found with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

On chrome it works fine but on Internet Explorer it throw: "The webpage cannot be found":

[image]

If normal characters for search paramater (a,b,c,d...  ) it works fines on both. But if special characters it only fines on Chrome. 
How can I fix on Internet Explorer

My code some thing like below.

```
<input id="tbSearch" name="tbSearch" type="text"  value="등록시">
<input id="btnSearch" name="tbSearch" type="button" value="Search">

$("#btnSearch").live("click", function () {
      $("#bz_ifmContent", parent.document).attr("src", "/UI/List.aspx?page=" + page + "&search=" + search);
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$("#btnSearch").live("click", function () {
      $("#bz_ifmContent", parent.document).attr("src", "/UI/List.aspx?page=" + encodeURIComponent(page) + "&search=" + encodeURIComponent(search));
   }
})
```